# sprite sheet animation in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, animation, sprite

I'm working on a simple iPad app which has an animation of 12 separate images using CAKeyFrameAnimation.

Just wondering what would be the simplest way to go with one sprite sheet and a plist file which describes that sprite instead of loading 12 separate images?

Comment: To answer my own question. I've used CGImageCreateWithImageInRect with coordinates from a plist file. The only problem I have is that my CGImage gets stretched to fill a CALayer where this images goes to. Any idea how to overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to load the spritesheet as a single image, load up the plist into bounds-normalized `CGRect`s, then use a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to animate the layer's `contentsRect` on the `@"sprite-animation"` key.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/1052332) contains the class I wrote. It doesn't have a method to load up a plist of animation names, frame indices, and timings, but it would be easy enough to write one. The main gotcha is that you must be sure to set the layer's `frameSize` or you won't get a working animation.

One side-note: I wanted to animate my sprites' movement by hand, so I set the `position` key to a null animation action in `-[SpriteLayer init]`. You may want to remove that line.